# changing bool state in a struct solidity

Tags: arrays, struct, boolean, mapping, solidity

I would change the bool state but it doesn't change.
I'm working on remix.
_roomNumber is required to the customer who have to indicate which room he wants.
I can check that the boolean not change by the index in hotelRoom array.

Thank you!

```
struct room {
string roomNumber;
uint256 cost;
bool avaiability;
}

mapping (uint => room) rooms;

room[] public hotelRooms;

function addRoom (uint _index, string memory _roomNumber, uint 
_cost) public {
    room storage r = rooms[_index];
    rooms[_index] = room(_roomNumber, _cost, true);
    hotelRooms.push(r);
    freeRooms ++;
}

function book(uint _roomNumber) public payable {
    require(rooms[_roomNumber-1].avaiability == true, "this room 
    is not avayable");
    require(msg.value >= rooms[_roomNumber-1].cost, "this room 
    costs much");
    payable(owner).transfer(msg.value);
    rooms[_roomNumber - 1].avaiability = false;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of room number you are passing as the parameters to the function. How and in what context are you calling the function? Inside remix? In a test suite? How are you checking that the boolean field did not change? Please provide more details, no one can help you with the current information you have provided.

Comment: Sorry for the lacks. I've edited the question. Thank you

Comment: So when you try running `addRoom` and `book` in remix, what values/parameters do you pass to the function?

Comment: addRoom(new index of the room, new room number, room's cost). avaiability is set to true automatically. Index and room's number increase equally but index starts to 0 and room's number to 1

Comment: book(room's number i want to book).

Comment: I'm sorry but you are again giving vague statements. What are the EXACT NUMBERS you are using when calling the functions? Also, your code has many issues: 1) I don't see the point of keeping an array and also a mapping of rooms. 2) You are not supposed to provide an index from the outside (in function `addRoom`) without checking if it is out of bounds. 3) Why are you decreasing the index by one in function `book`